# Datatable + Pjax Document ready working but doesn't work pjax end or start

Tags: jquery, datatables, pjax

When I refresh the page datatable listing but pjax end or pjax start not working.

```
$(document).on('pjax:end ready', function () {
    PCFilterButton();
});

function PCFilterButton(aPage) {

    var myTable = $('#tblpaymentList').dataTable({
        "paging": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "bDestroy": true,
        "responsive": true,
        "processing": true,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bFilter": false,``
        "ajax": {
            "url": "list-data"
         }

         .....
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Load pjax on documente ready then reload pjax like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).pjax('a', '#div_content_page')
          $.pjax.reload('#div_content_page')
      })

    $(document).on('pjax:end ready', function () {
        PCFilterButton();
    });
```